# RESTful servise

Tags: java, eclipse, rest

I want create RESTful web service on java, i chosen eclipse auto generating  and got this code.

```
@Path("/message")
public class Rest_test {

    @Context
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public Rest_test() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of Rest_test
     * @return an instance of String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public String getXml() {
        // TODO return proper representation object
        return "sdfgdsd";
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of Rest_test
     * @param content representation for the resource
     * @return an HTTP response with content of the updated or created resource.
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public void putXml(String content) {
    }

}
```

For testing my app i use program Postman and call my server from this adrres
`localhost:8080/test/rest/message`
but i always have same page **HTTP Status 404 - Not Found**. Please Help me

Comment: class name is Rest_test and you're trying to point into /test/rest maybe you missed order? I guessing because I don't see rest of the defined path.

Comment: @Mariusz Nosiński, if i am right in second place i should write name of project, and my project called test

Comment: You need to add details of how your application is packaged and how it is being deployed. I'd suspect the app isn't getting deployed with the 'test' context.

Comment: @emeraldjava if it help i will show my web.xml

Comment: Why do you have rest in the URL path, i think you should be calling 'http://localhost:8080/test/message'.

Comment: @emeraldjava i did this way, too

Answer (score 0):

the comments are correct! you should call:
localhost:8080/nameOfYourService/rest/message

I have also an TestWebService and cannot call it out of the blue.

I created an local client app and use a httpURLconnection:

```
private class yourTestApp {
....
public static void getStringOrWhatEver() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/<nameOfYourService>/rest/message");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("...and the message is: ");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        System.out.println(".... End of content\n");
        conn.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.err.println("MalformedURLException, " + ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("IOException, " + ex);
    }
}
....
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvEfm.jpg)

for you "ps" should be "message"

Comment: where i can find my  nameOfMyService?

Comment: name = name of the WebServiceApplication (Is it "test")

Comment: slowly I got the same impression as emeraldjava - did you run your webservice? Do you have an Webserver in place? Sorry I'm using Netbeans with a tomcat in the background. - cannot help with Eclipse

Comment: yes i run my webservice, wait minutes i try send screenshot of postman